# Problem to name multiple macros from lua variables

Tags: luatex, lua

Suppose I have three numerical variables `a,b,c` and I want to use them in TeX then I write :

```
  token.set_macro("a",a,'global')
  token.set_macro("b",b,'global') 
  token.set_macro("c",c,'global')
```

I would like not to have to write "a", "b" and "c" and if possible treat all cases together, something like f(a,b,c).

After some research I found a very heavy solution [With debug.getlocal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458306/get-name-of-argument-of-function-in-lua)

Is it possible to find another solution?

Finally the question should be: if pi=3.14 how to write
`tex.print("pi" .."="..tostring(pi))` without duplicating `pi`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416815/lua-get-the-literal-name-of-the-parameter (just in case you didn't find this yourself, the `icecream`-answer looks interesting, imho)

Comment: @Skillmon yes I have seen this solution but I would like my package to be independent of external modules

Comment: Generally-speaking "real" programming languages instead of TeX doesn't do this. e.g. [python - How do I create variable variables? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite the form you asked for but it's easier to iterate over a table

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
t={
 a=11,
 b=22,
 c=33
}
function f (t)
 for k,v in pairs(t) do
  token.set_macro(k,v,'global')
 end
end
f(t)
}

\show\a
\show\b
\show\c


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
> \a=macro:
->11.
l.17 \show\a
          
? 
> \b=macro:
->22.
l.18 \show\b
          
? 
> \c=macro:
->33.
l.19 \show\c
          
?
```

showing all three macros are set.

---

Or if you want to use variables, iterate over the *names*

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{

a=11
b=22
c=33

function f (t)
 for k,v in pairs(t) do
  token.set_macro(v,_G[v],'global')
 end
end
f{"a","b","c"}
}

\show\a
\show\b
\show\c


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not really practical because if I don't write the name of the variable twice, I have to rewrite the value of the variable. Unfortunately `a` and `b` for example are the radii of an ellipse ...

Comment: @AlainMatthes not sure what you mean, in Lua you can more or less always use table entries rather than global variables if you wish. a global variable is just an entry in the `_G` table so there isn't  really any difference. but  otherwise use variables and a function call `f("a","b","c"}` and get the values from `_G`

Comment: @AlainMatthes I added a version using variables

Comment: Yes, this version is easier to use. It is a mix with the Skillmon one.

Answer (score 5):

You could go the other way round: instead of trying to retrieve the variable name as a string, retrieve the variable value from a string.

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
pi = 3.14
function print_debug(name)
  if _G[name] then
    tex.print(name.."=".._G[name])
  else
    tex.print(name.." not found")
  end
end
}

\begin{document}
\directlua{print_debug("pi")}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd prefer `_ENV` over `_G` since most variables shouldn't be global

Comment: @MaxChernoff yes, but this is a minimal example :) I'd even more prefer a module-specific table, or providing the module-table in which to search as a second argument (with global as default?).

Comment: @Skillmon How to proceed in the case of `a, b and c`? i.e. with a set of variables

Comment: @Skillmon Finally I have the solution in David' answer.